# Azure build Agent

Tags: java, linux, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-pipelines-tasks

**Situation:** During the build process of an azure pipeline i use the JavaToolInstaller on a self hosted agent and it places "java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_" in the directory 
**Background:** I dont believe this to be a permission issue when i have applied full permissions to that directory and created it for the build process 
**Assessment:** Has anyone see this issue before?

Steps to reproduce - host onsite agent

**JavaToolInstaller**

```
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: '/opt/jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '/opt/java'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
  condition: eq( variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux' )
```

**Error during build**

```
Cleaning destination folder before extraction: /opt/java
Retrieving the JDK from local path.
##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: ExtractingArchiveToPath
ExtractingArchiveToPath /opt/java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_jdk-8u251-linux-x64_tar.gz
Creating destination folder: /opt/java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_jdk-8u251-linux-x64_tar.gz
##[error]Unable to create directory '/opt/java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_jdk-8u251-linux-x64_tar.gz'. EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_jdk-8u251-linux-x64_tar.gz'
##[error]Unable to create directory '/opt/java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_jdk-8u251-linux-x64_tar.gz'. EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/java/JAVA_HOME_8_x64_jdk-8u251-linux-x64_tar.gz'
Finishing: JavaToolInstaller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems that you do not have permission to write this file. Please check it and ensure that you have w and r permission for this folder

Steps:

Locate the file jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz->right-click on the icon->select Properties->click the tab permission then check the account permission

Or use the cmd `ls –l {file name}` to check the folder permission, then run the cmd c`hmod [permission] [file_name]` to update the permission

Please refer this link for more details: [How to change directory permissions in Linux](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-file-permissions)

Comment: I added permissions to the /java folder chmod 777 java
Also I didn't realise that the statement above requires jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz to be present in the /opt folder to run.